# Convert gridview data to list or xml with updated values

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, gridview

I'm having `GridView` control and I have bind it with object data source and I want to provide facility of changing values using edit template.

When row updating is fired I want my gridview data to be converted in XML or list so that I can pass that values to stored procedure. Any hint how to do that?

Comment: Ever consider using an ORM for this? It makes it much easier than doing everything by hand. Entity Framework is OK, but there's lots of others. I say check those out before anything.

Comment: ok but i have developed whole project using EF 4.0 and Linq. and stuck here..it would be great if i find any solution this way only..

Comment: You need the updated row data in the List or the Whole grid view data in the List...?

Comment: Why do you need to convert it to XML in order to pass it to the stored procedure?

Comment: Yes. i have created a stored procedure which accepts XML as parameters and updates the values in database from supplied XML data. In order to do that i need to convert the Gridview data into XML.